# How to delete and start over for pipedrive account

Tags: pipedrive-api

I was having issues with current data, and wanted to start over the full account. Found out, there is a link which you can hit to start over again.

Here is the link to delete everything.

https://app.pipedrive.com/settings/start_over

Answer (score 0):

Following this link i was able to delete everything on the account. https://app.pipedrive.com/settings/start_over